# Run entire website on https, except API URLs under http

Tags: magento-1.9, api, ssl

I have a whole shop set up under https (unsecure and secure URL set to https), because 1) I do not see why not and 2) I use a theme from themeforest which has problems with mixing http and https (exclamation mark in the address bar because of mixed secure and unsecure content, and ugly security warning when putting stuff into the shopping cart).

Unfortunately, the shop POS system can ONLY use the API via http (yes, seems out of date and risky, but they won't change it).

I tried playing around with the `.htaccess` and rewrite everything under `/api` from https to http, but did not find a solution, the whole system goes into a redirect loop. I guess the problem lies between the htaccess redirect and the Magento internal redirection system.

Since this is a very specific problem, I did not really find a solution, even after googling for hours.

Can anybody give me pointers on what possibilities I have in order to achieve a complete https setup with just the API URLs unsecure?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, didn't test this but should work. Since the API doesn't work on a store level (it uses 0) you could set the base urls to `https` on all websites but leave it as `http` on global scope.

Please find attached some amazing artwork that explains what I mean.

[image]

Comment: That is actually a great idea. Played around with it and while it seems to work in principle it does something strange with the API:

I set everything to http:// on global, but to https:// on store level. 

The store continues to work great on all https://.

When trying to access the api on http:// it just redirects to the "root" website. When accessing on https://, it works.

So while the idea works on some level, it fails in a new way on the API URL :(

Answer (score 1):

What comes close to your problem is SSL offloading, e.g. at load balancers. In those cases, the secure connection never reaches Magento itself and you need a way to tell the system that all is fine and there is no need to redirect.

This is what the *System → Configuration → Web → Secure → Offloader header* is available for.

So I suggest setting that server environment variable when the Request_URI matches the API resource path.